# Are there normal long-haired male Vulcans?

Tags: star-trek

The typical Vulcan is depicted as short-haired guy with long robe. I can't recall seeing a male Vulcan with long hair.

Sure, Spock once did in *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*, but I recall that he's been in a kind of exile (please correct me if wrong). And after they returned him to the Enterprise, he got a fresh and clean short hair cut.

I also Googled a bit, but the only thing I've found has been [50 Shades of Long and Prosper](http://fanlore.org/wiki/Long-Haired_Spock).

**Spoiler alert: Not safe for people who can't look at a naked male torso.**

> [image]

[image]

After that I went a bit thinking. Sure we only see short-haired male Vulcans, but we mostly also see military or persons of publicity. And even on our world "The Businessman" wears a suit and short hair. So maybe these occurances are just situational. Military haircut? Business and ambassador haircut?

It's like Klingons: Sure they're all with blood and honour, but we also know that there are normal folks on Qo'noS like smiths, engineers or vendors.

**So are there long-haired male Vulcans in canon?** By that I don't mean Vulcans in exile or not in favor of a barber. Just normal citizens having long hair.

Because what can be more metal than being born on a vulcan?

Comment: a) that picture is horrifying b) long hair is illogical. I don't remember a single one, but my memery isn't good enough to make that an answer

Comment: a) My reference to 50 implies that. b) Yes, so do I. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: A vulcan going against the norm of short hair would be accused of having a personality and emotions

Comment: @Petersaber Speak for yourself! Ain't no [slash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_fiction#History) like the one true slash! :D :D :D

Comment: @cde Your comment illogically contradicts ["infinite *diversity* in infinite combinations"](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/IDIC). ;) Any good scientist will tell you that variation is fundamental to the universe. Ergo, Vulcans must embrace difference.

Comment: So the answer would be that there are no long-haired badass Spocks in Vulcan society? (As I stated: mad, exiled or similars are excepted)

Comment: AND WHY DO I INVESTIGATE @Lexible 's SUGGESTION!? THIS IS DISTUR--- wow... those are some pointy ears...

Comment: @Lex a cheap plot to sell merchandise. And everything we see about Vulcans is a monoculture of emotional repression. They look down on human boldness and uniqueness at the very least of individuality. Their symbol might promote diversity but every action and representation of vulcan do not.

Comment: @cde OH IT IS ***ON!!!*** ;)

Comment: May someone please explain the downvotes for me? I think it is a normal question and I'd like to improve it.

Comment: @Trollwut it wasn't me... but I was tempted to downvote for the image alone. That's just... horrible.

Comment: I think the image is rad. And I do not think the question should be down-voted. Even if I did find the image horrible, instead of, say, *fascinating*, I would not down-vote this.

Comment: @Omegacron Believe me, on my search of "long haired vulcan" this is one of the not-so-disturbing pictures. As the linked site says, fanfiction often writes about Spock and Kirk having a romantic relationship. I'm gonna replace the former image with a more... fitting one. BTW: Gay marriage is now legal in the whole US and A.

Comment: Keep the original image!!!

Comment: @Lexible Spoilers do work, now I got a compromise. Would love to have a webcam on homophobic guys who accidently hover... :D

Comment: Alright now - there's a difference between "homophobic" and just not caring to see that sort of thing. And just because something is legal does not mean that it's widely accepted. But that's a debate for another time.

Comment: No need to justify, didn't mean that as an offense. Sorry if it sounded like that! Just wanted to be a bit cheeky that a disturbing image doesn't make the question itself bad. :)

Comment: Np @Trollwut - I'm probably a little touchy given the events of the past week. You would not believe how often I've been called a racist homophobe the past few days, with little reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image you posted has scarred me for life, but **yes, Vulcan males can grow their hair out just like a human male can. However, 99.9% of Vulcan males keep their hair short on purpose.**

The short-cropped hairstyle seen on most Vulcan males is a sign of their devotion to the teachings of [Surak](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Surak). In fact, chronologically-speaking, Surak is the first Vulcan male we see sporting the hairstyle (ENT S04E08 "[The Awakening](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Awakening_(episode))"), so we could speculate that the trend started with him.

Even those who follow Surak occasionally grow their hair out long, although this is only seen when away from society. This is seen on Spock in [**Star Trek: The Motion Picture**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture) as you mentioned, but is also seen on [Syrran](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Arev), a follower of Surak in the 22nd Century.

[image]

When we first see Spock in TMP, he is finishing the rite of [Kolinahr](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kolinahr), which means he has been living a monastic life of solitude for a period of at least two years. When we see Syrran, he also has been living in solitude, wandering the desert for an unknown period of time.

Spock's brother [Sybok](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sybok), on the other hand, has rejected (or rather, reinterpreted) the teachings of Surak and believes that much of what Vulcan society has embraced - logic, lack of emotion - is a perversion of Surak's actual intent. As a result, he wears his hair long as a sign of this rejection. This is a highly unusual case where a Vulcan male allows his hair to grow out on purpose, and is the only case we know of within Star Trek canon.

Comment: Darn it, Omegacron, I thought we all agreed **never to speak of *ST V* again!**

Comment: For clarification: Has he returned to society? As I recall from *The Film we can't name* Sybok has been abondened by society. My question refers to if there are normal long-haired male Vulcan citizen. :)

Comment: @Trollwut: Ah, apologies - I read the question as asking if Vulcans COULD grow their hair out. I'll expand on the answer.

Comment: @Lexible yea, yea, I know. I was young and needed the money.

Comment: Yeah, this answer is pretty rad now! The last sentence made it exact. Thanks mate!

Comment: "The Film we can't name"... So, the "V" in "Star Trek V" stands for Voldemort?